# How do I make BGE recognize multiple XBOX Controllers?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

So right now I have a splitscreen FPS on Windows.  I have the players set up by using the Joystick Sensor when the XBOX controller is plugged in.  When I have two controllers plugged in, both controllers control both players.  I want it so one controller controls one player and the other controls the other.  Is there a way to make blender recognize the controller?  If I can't do this than I will have to make it so one person uses the keyboard and mouse and the other uses the controller which would not be as good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Index` field on the *Joystick* sensor, to distinguish between different controllers.

[image]

Comment: Does the index just specify what controller it is ( like a play station or Xbox controller) or does it specify which of the two controllers is two Xbox controllers were plugged in?

Comment: From my understanding, it builds an array of the connected controllers; then the index would be the position in said array - meaning it distinguishes between which controller is being used, as opposed to which type it is.